# Classes and packages encapsulation in an hexagonal architecture

Tags: java, package, encapsulation, hexagonal-architecture, archunit

I would like to know if in Java (JDK 17) there is a way to easily handle classes and packages encapsulation in an hexagonal architure. I would like to make unavailable classes present in an `adapter` to the domain.
To illustrate my goal, say we have this package organisation:

```
com.company
           |-domain
                  |-model
                        |-Customer.java
                        |-Product.java
                  |-ports
                        |-DbPort.java
                        |-ServiceBusPort.java
                  |-services
                           |-CustomerService.java
                           |-ProductService.java
           |-adapters 
                   |-inbound
                           |-rest
                               |-CustomerRestAdapter.java
                               |-ProductRestAdapter.java
                           |-bus
                               |-ServiceBusAdapter.java
                               |-RabbitAdapter.java
                   |-outbound
                           |-db
                              |-entities
                                      |-Customer.java
                                      |-Product.java
                              |-repositories
                                      |-CustomerRepository.java
                                      |-ProductRepository.java
                              |-mappers
                           |-bus
                               |-dtos
                                   |-CutomerDto.java
                                   |-ProductDto.java
                               |-mappers
```

What I want to achieve is: all classes and packages under `com.company.adapters` should not be visible from the `com.company.domain` package. The goal is to prevent developers to use for example the class `com.company.adapters.outbound.db.entities.Customer` in `com.company.domain.services.CustomerService`. But classes inside `com.company.domain` should be accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve strong encapsulation with Java, you could make use of maven modules per layer, left, right and domain.
I have not tried but I guess Java 9 modules would also help here. Check [this link](https://medium.com/swlh/a-practical-example-of-applying-java-modules-in-a-hexagonal-architecture-d345deec654b).

Another approach I use for the sake of simplicity and code readability, is to use a single module, without strong encapsulation, but different packages per layers, one for domain, another for infra..

And, to **enforce architecture rules** within this module, like hexagonal ones, I usually define a unit test which fails in case of any violation, for example when some domain package code directly depends on a technical API client implem defined outside the domain.
So far I have used [Archunit](https://www.archunit.org/) framework for that.

Also I prefer this approach because, as a developer or new joiner for example, IMO it is much easier to break some architecture rules / encapsulation patterns, not being aware till the code review, rather than breaking / ignoring a test which would fail the build, and which would also act as a spec for these rules.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know ArchUnit and I think that could help a lot if it works. My first idea was to divide the application into multiple maven modules but I would like to keep things simple. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is definitey doable in Java.

There are numerous examples - for example check out the JAXP library:

While you use the DocumentBuilderFactory to instantiate a DocumentBuilder and ultimately parse a Document, everything but the factory are interfaces abstracting away a concise implementation, which is the pattern you are aiming at.

To get more concise: All that you need to do is come up with the right combination of classes, interfaces and packages. Have a look at [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) which describe what you need to do. The book ["Design Patterns" by the Gang of Four](https://springframework.guru/gang-of-four-design-patterns/) is very helpful in that respect.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how your answer could solve my issue.

Comment: Grant. You need something that directs you towards decisions and tasks. I refined my answer.

Comment: It’s not related to the design, I want a physical solution to reduce the scope of classes. I am looking at using modules introduced in Java 9.

Comment: If you have bad design, how are packages and modules going to help?

Comment: How hexagonal architecture is a bad design? I found this article which could help: https://medium.com/swlh/a-practical-example-of-applying-java-modules-in-a-hexagonal-architecture-d345deec654b

Comment: It seems I underestimated the hexagonal architecture. You are done with that part.
So have fun with modules now. :-)