# What sub-packages are recommended to use to dispatch classes when creating an hexagonal architecture for a Java (here spring-boot) application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, package, hexagonal-architecture

I discovered the hexagonal architecture and I'm willing to apply it on a rather large *Spring Boot* application.

A *stackoverflow* user started a question with a list of sub-packages looking to me really convenient to use, or at least to think about, in this [Classes and packages encapsulation in an hexagonal architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198158/classes-and-packages-encapsulation-in-an-hexagonal-architecture) question.

The questioner was planning to use a list of packages starting that way:

```
[....].domain.model
[....].domain.ports
[....].domain.services

[....].adapters.inbound
[....].adapters.inbound.rest
[....].adapters.inbound.bus

[....].adapters.outbound
[....].adapters.outbound.db
[....].adapters.outbound.db.entities
[....].adapters.outbound.db.repositories
[....].adapters.outbound.db.mappers

[....].adapters.outbound.bus
[....].adapters.outbound.bus.dtos
[....].adapters.outbound.bus.mappers
```

What are the most complete lists of sub-packages recommended to use (or to think about) when creating an hexagonal architecture?

I know: it depends of the kind of application I'm doing, that's true. But in general, if you had to do a template, in this given example of twelve first packages, what would you add, change?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably rename the `domain` to `core` and inside of the core, I would 2 more packages domains, and applications.

```
core
 |___ domain
 |___ application
```

inside the domain, I would add more packages such as `entities`, `value objects`, and `domain events`. However, this preference is leaning more toward following a DDD approach that uses hexagonal architecture. I would also move `ports` under `application`.

Hence you would have something similar to:

```
core
 |___ domain
 |      |_ entities
 |      |_ events 
 |      |_ valueObjects
 |
 |___ application
         |_ services
         |_ ports
```

But, it is worth mentioning that Uncle Bob, emphasizes the importance of aligning your application architecture with your domain. He argues that the architecture of a software system should reflect the business domain it serves, rather than the particular technical details of the application.

Hence, as long your core/domain is independent of any other detail (UI, database, external system) you should be fine.

regarding the other packages you have already mentioned,  I would probably leave them the same.

*Edited*:

Regarding the `domain.entities` or (`domain.model`) that represents your domain, you would still have `db.entities` that are used for persistence. For example, if you are developing a spring boot application and let's say you are using JPA to help in persistence, and your in the context of an `OrderService`. Typically you you would have in your domain (an entity [in DDD] or model [the name you used in your case]) called Order that is purely a Java object:

```
public class Order {
  private String id;
  ....
 
  //constructors, other functions ... 
}
```

However, on the `adapters.outbound.db.entities` you will have the persistence object of this order domain that would have annotations such as `@Entity` for example. if you are wondering why you can use this annotation here because you are at the level of the infra where you can are allowed to use ORMs or other technical details technology. Hence you would end up with:

```
@Entity
public class OrderEntity {

  @Id
  private String id;
  ....
 
 
}
```

Notice how in the example above am now using hibernate/JPA syntax, in the future if you decide to change to a different ORM you could simply change the `OrderEntity` instead of your core model `Order` since the latter should only change for business requirements and not for technical details. So in my previous answer `domain.entities` does not reflect the persistence model but the Domain model which reflects your business objects. To move from your `Order` to `OrderEntity` you would basically do mapping between these two classes by making sure the `core` does not depend on the `infra`. Meaning that at no point in time, you shall see `OrderEntity` in your imports when you are in the core. But vice versa is possible (finding `Order` in the infra layer) because your external/infra/.. should depend on core.

Regarding `domain.ValueObject`, in brief value object is an immutable object that represents a concept or an entity that is identified by its attributes rather than its identity these can be used to typically model concepts such as date, time, money... Let's take an example:

Your order would probably have a price, instead of having a double value that represents the price of this order you would probably create a `Money` value object.

```
public class Order {
  private String id;
  private Money price;
  ....
 
  //constructors, other functions ... 
}

public class Money {
 private final BigDecimal amount;

  // conversion functions
  // rouding
}
```

So probably now you are wondering the reason behind this encapsulation. Well, one example behind this encapsulation:

1. The Money Value Object can encapsulate all the rules and calculations related to money in the domain, such as currency conversion, rounding, and formatting. This couldn't be achieved by having a simple `double price` field without leaking information to the `Order` model or by creating for example an `OrderPriceCalculator` service.

Whereas for the persistence model `OrderEntity` once you are mapping from `Order` to `OrderEntity` the `OrderEntity` could now have the price as a `double` property since you are just persisting the `Order` model, and now logic or conversion should be occurring at this level.

In summary, these added concepts are well-known in the DDD space as previously mentioned. I would encourage to read about the topic as it would help in designing your application.

Comment: I agree with `application.services` and `application.ports` in core, but I think `domain.entities` relates to adapters part. Does `domain.valueObjects` mean business objects (POJOs?). If true, it's ok. If they are dto, I would send them to adapters package also.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I have edited my answer above to better answer your questions